# How to download Fedora Packages on windows?

Tags: windows, fedora, yum, packages

My Fedora has no internet connection but my Windows has.

I want to download **some packages and their dependencies** on windows and then install those packages on my Fedora. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Fedora Package Database](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb). 
You can search for a package and on its "Detail Page" ([Example](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/package/python26/)) you can click on "Builds Status", choose the version you need and you get to a page conatining the RPMs for downloading ([Example](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=365045)). Dependencies can be viewed on the "info" link for every package.